# Defining Hash Values and Keys and Using Multiple Different Files

Tags: perl, hash, multidimensional-array

I am struggling with writing a Perl program for several tasks. I have tried really hard to review all errors since I am a beginner and want to understand my mistakes, but I am failing. Hopefully, my description of the tasks and my deficient program so far will not be confusing.

In my current directory, I have a variable number of “.txt.” files. (I can have 4, 5, 8, or any number of files. However, I don’t think I will get more that 17 files.) The format of the “.txt” files is the same. There are six columns, which are separated by white space. I only care about two columns in these files: the second column, which is the coral reef regionID (made up of letters and numbers), and the fifth column, which is the p-value. The number of rows in each file is undetermined. What I need to do is find all the common regionIDs in all .txt files and print these common regions to an outfile. However, before printing, I must sort them.

The following is my program so far, but I have received error messages, which I have included after the program. Thus, my definitions of variables are the major problems. I really appreciate any suggestions for writing the program and thank you for your patience with a beginner like me.

UPDATE: I have declared the variables as suggested. After reviewing my program, two syntax errors appear.

```
   syntax error at oreg.pl line 19, near "$hash{"
   syntax error at oreg.pl line 23, near "}"
   Execution of oreg.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Here is an excerpt of the edited program that includes where said errors are.

```
#!/user/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
# Trying to read files in @txtfiles for reading into hash
foreach my $file (@txtfiles) {
  open(FH,"<$file") or die "Can't open $file\n";
  while(chomp(my $line = <FH>)){
    $line =~ s/^\s+//;      
    my @IDp = split(/\s+/, $line); # removing whitespace
    my $i = 0;
    # trying to define values and keys in terms of array elements in IDp
    my $value = my $hash{$IDp[$i][1]};
    $value .= "$IDp[$i][4]"; # confused here at format to append p-values
    $i++;       
  }                         
}

close(FH);
```

These are past errors:

```
Global symbol "$file" requires explicit package name at oreg.pl line 13.
Global symbol "$line" requires explicit package name at oreg.pl line 16.
#[And many more just like that...]
Execution of oreg.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't declare `$file`.

```
foreach my $file (@txtfiles) {
```

You didn't declare `$line`.

```
while(chomp(my $line = <FH>)){
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. I apologize, but I am confused by what is meant by "declare."

Comment: With 'use strict' you must declare variables e.g. with 'my $variable' before using them.

Comment: @user2174373, Appropriate use of `my`, as shown in my answer.

Comment: If I don't have "use strict," then would I get any error messages? (And I wouldn't have to use "my"?) I thank you both.

Comment: Two wrongs don't make a right. Don't remove `use strict;` to avoid fixing your scoping.

Comment: Thank you, ikegami. I have declared all variables and have not received any error messages. However, when I open the outfile, it is blank, save the title label. There must be something extremely wrong in how I've written any lines. I would really appreciate any guidance. Thank you for everything.

Comment: I loathe to speculate about a program I haven't seen. Why don't you ask another question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ikegami. I have edited the post to reflect the program with the declared variables. After reviewing and working the program again, two syntax errors appear: `syntax error at oreg.pl line 19, near "$hash{"`
`syntax error at oreg.pl line 23, near "}"`
`Execution of oreg.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`  Thank you again.

Comment: A hash is declared using `my %hash;`. You'll want to do this outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %region;
foreach my $file (@txtfiles) {
  open my $FH, "<", $file or die "Can't open $file \n";
  while (my $line = <$FH>) {
    chomp($line);
    my @values = split /\s+/, $line;
    my $regionID = $values[1]; # 2nd column, per your notes
    my $pvalue = $values[4]; # 5th column, per your notes
    $region{$regionID} //= []; # Inits this value in the hash to an empty arrayref if undefined
    push @{$region{$regionID}}, $pvalue;
  }                         
}
# Now sort and print using %region as needed
```

At the end of this code, `%region` is a hash where the keys are the region IDs and the values are array references containing the various pvalues.

Here's a few snippets that may help you with next steps:

`keys %regions` will give you a list of region id values.

`my @pvals = @{$regions{SomeRegionID}}` will give you the list of pvalues for SomeRegionID

`$regions{SomeRegionID}->[0]` will give you the first pvalue for that region.

You may want to check out Data::Printer or Data::Dumper - they are CPAN modules that will let you easily print out your data structure, which might help you understand what's going on in your code.